# How to read and render data from a react-redux persisted store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I am trying to output the data from a React store into a component. I am using redux-persist to maintain the data across the site when the page reloads. However, I can't figure out how to get the data to render onto the page. I tried using the { useSelector } hook from react-redux on the component, but that isn't rendering the data from the store onto the page. I am also using React-toolkit.

```
Index.js:

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from "./store";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist'

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
let persistor = persistStore(store)

root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>
)



Component:

import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export default function Cart() {
  const cartItems = useSelector((state) => state.test)

  return <div className='pt-20'>{cartItems}</div>
}


Store:

import { configureStore, combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import cartReducer from './slices/cartSlice'
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage"
import { 
  persistReducer, 
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER, 
} from "redux-persist"

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  version: 1,
  storage
}

const reducer = combineReducers({
  cart: cartReducer,
})

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer)

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),
})

export default store

Cart Slice:

import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
  cartItems: [],
  cartTotalQuantity: 0,
  cartTotalAmount: 0,
  test: 'hello',
}

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addToCart(state, action) {
      state.cartItems.push(action.payload)
    },
    removeFromCart(state, action) {
      state.cartItems.pop(action.payload)
    },
    increment(state) {
      state.counter++
    },
    resetPrice(state) {
      state.counter = 0
    },
  },
})

export const cartActions = cartSlice.actions

export default cartSlice.reducer
```

Answer (score 0):

The `cartSlice` state is:

```
const initialState = {
  cartItems: [],
  cartTotalQuantity: 0,
  cartTotalAmount: 0,
  test: 'hello',
}
```

and when the Redux store is instantiated the `cartSlice.reducer` is placed under a `cart` property.

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
  cart: cartReducer, // <-- cartSlice.reducer function
})

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer)

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [.....],
      },
    }),
});
```

The UI `Cart` component is simply not accessing into the Redux `state` correctly. The `useSelector` hook's callback is passed the ***entire*** Redux state object, and the correct path into nested properties should be observed. `state.cart`, then `state.cart.test`, or `state.cart.cartItems` ot get the array, etc.

```
export default function Cart() {
  const test = useSelector((state) => state.cart.test);

  return <div className='pt-20'>{test}</div> // "hello"
}
```